Flutter data returning error in debug console
I stored MillisecondsSinceEpoch in Firestore which is stored in a field as number.
I want to retrieve the data in a Text widget so I convert it to DateTimeFormat.
In the UI everything is good. But in the debug console, I'm getting this error type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'int'.
MY CODE
After streamBuild...

final deptTime = snapshot.data?.get("TimeToStart") //I also tried snapshot.data?.get("TimeToStart") ?? ""
final startTime = DateFormat("hh:mm a")
                     .format((DateTime
                             .fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(deptTime)));
.....
Text(startTime)

What can I do to remove the error in the debug console?

when you call startTime in Text(startTime), the deptTime is null. Did you already check the value of deptTime using print or devtools?

Since deptTime is supposed to receive an Integer value, you shouldn't assign a string to it in case of the field TimeToStart is null
final deptTime = snapshot.data?.get("TimeToStart")?? DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;

...

Note:

the named constructor DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(intValue)
requires an integer value as a positional parameter.


make sure, snapshot.data?.get("TimeToStart") returns an integer if
not, cast it to integer.

